# поиск расшаренных файлов на amazonaws

Tags: администрирование, amazon-web-services, облако, amazon-s3

есть облако на **s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com**, на котором лежит несколько файлов.
облако не мое, кто владелец хз, на нем расшарено несколько файлов, которые доступны для скачивания по прямой ссылке.
И так получилось, что к паре файлов ссылка была утрачена, и спустя некоторое время мне они потребовались.
Как узнать прямую ссылку ко всем файлам в расшаренной папке, чтобы я мог найти и скачать недостающие? Или как найти нужные файлы, если я примерно помню как называется файл?

Comment: Если вебсервер не отдаёт дерево директорий, то скорее всего - никак. Ну или поискать в гугле. Может конкретная нода проиндексировалась и твои прямые ссылки помнит кэш поисковика.

Answer (score 1):

Если открыт доступ к файлам, то есть вероятность что открыт и доступ к просмотру списка файлов. Для этого можно попробовать установить aws cli, настроить ключи доступа (aws configure) и попробовать запустить такую команду:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive
```